# QGIS 3.0 - qConsolidate or similar plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

It appears that the qConsolidate has not been updated for Qgis 3.0. Are there any alternative plugins/functions available for exporting all layers and saving the project to a new folder?

Comment: hope the qConsolidate plugin gets updated for 3.0 as well. very handy and easy way to take your QGIS projects to QField!

Comment: it seams that qconsolidate has been ported to qgis3 now, not in the official repo yet. but available from here: https://plugins.bruy.me/plugins/plugins.xml

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[QPackage plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QPackage/) is very similar alternative to qConsolidate plugin in QGIS 3.

> **Qpackage is a tool to save both your QGIS project and data contained in the project to a new directory.**
>
> It allows to convert any GIS vector format towards the .shp only. You may also apply a new projection.

**EDIT**: **[QConsolidate3](https://github.com/danzig666/qconsolidate3)** plugin, modified version of QConsolidate, for QGIS 3 has been released.

Comment: Note that this plugin does not actually work for projects built with QGIS 2.X.X

Comment: note that it converts all your data to SHP files, which might be a lossy process. not to mention all the drawback of shapefiles. But if that is what you are after it does the job nicely